# Endpoint returns presumably cloud config

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-cloud

I have this simple controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/metrics")
public class MetricsController {

    @GetMapping
    @ApiOperation("Get metrics by source")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Metric>> getMetricBySource(@RequestParam String source) {
        if (source.equalsIgnoreCase("recordings")) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(MetricsConstants.RECORDINGS_METRICS, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else if (source.equalsIgnoreCase("advertisers")) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(MetricsConstants.ADVERTISERS_METRICS, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else if (source.equalsIgnoreCase("publishers")) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(MetricsConstants.PUBLISHERS_METRICS, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else if (source.equalsIgnoreCase("partners")) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(MetricsConstants.PARTNERS_METRICS, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else if (source.equalsIgnoreCase("products")) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(MetricsConstants.PRODUCTS_METRICS, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else if (source.equalsIgnoreCase("regular-users")) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(MetricsConstants.REGULAR_USERS_METRICS, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Now, when I'm trying to access the endpoint via
`localhost:8099/metrics?source=advertisers`

I'm getting the following response

> {
>       "mem": 947258,
>       "mem.free": 367038,
>       "processors": 4,
>       "instance.uptime": 540532,
>       "uptime": 556754,
>       "systemload.average": -1,
>       "heap.committed": 854016,
>       "heap.init": 260096,
>       "heap.used": 486977,
>       "heap": 3699200,
>       "nonheap.committed": 95312,
>       "nonheap.init": 2496,
>       "nonheap.used": 93242,
>       "nonheap": 0,
>       "threads.peak": 61,
>       "threads.daemon": 37,
>       "threads.totalStarted": 128,
>       "threads": 53,
>       "classes": 13916,
>       "classes.loaded": 13916,
>       "classes.unloaded": 0,
>       "gc.ps_scavenge.count": 13,
>       "gc.ps_scavenge.time": 150,
>       "gc.ps_marksweep.count": 3,
>       "gc.ps_marksweep.time": 341,
>       "counter.servo.eurekaclient.transport.request": 0,
>       "counter.servo.eurekaclient.transport.connectionerrors": 0,
>       "counter.servo.timeouts": 0,
>       "counter.servo.rejectedexecutions": 0,
>       "counter.servo.throwables": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.threadpoolused": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.response.metrics": 6,
>       "normalized.servo.rest.totaltime": 0,
>       "normalized.servo.rest.count": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.rest.min": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.rest.max": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.registration.lastheartbeatsec_00030": 0,
>       "counter.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_reuse": 10,
>       "counter.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_createnew": 26,
>       "counter.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_request": 36,
>       "counter.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_release": 36,
>       "counter.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_delete": 24,
>       "normalized.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_requestconnectiontimer.totaltime":
>   0.005046033333333333,
>       "normalized.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_requestconnectiontimer.count":
>   0.06666666666666667,
>       "gauge.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_requestconnectiontimer.min":
>   0.017749,
>       "gauge.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_requestconnectiontimer.max":
>   0.12356299999999999,
>       "normalized.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_createconnectiontimer.totaltime":
>   0.0012743166666666665,
>       "normalized.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_createconnectiontimer.count":
>   0.05,
>       "gauge.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_createconnectiontimer.min":
>   0.012288,
>       "gauge.servo.discoveryclient-httpclient_createconnectiontimer.max":
>   0.034475,
>       "gauge.servo.connectioncount": 2,
>       "normalized.servo.eurekaclient.transport.latency.totaltime": 0,
>       "normalized.servo.eurekaclient.transport.latency.count": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.transport.latency.min": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.transport.latency.max": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.response.star-star.favicon.ico": 42,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.registry.lastupdatesec_00240": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.registration.lastheartbeatsec_00015": 1,
>       "gauge.servo.response.webjars.star-star": 5,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.resolver.endpointssize": 1,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.resolver.lastloadtimestamp": 233376,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.registration.lastheartbeatsec_00240": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.transport.quarantinesize": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.registry.lastupdatesec_00030": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.response.v2.api-docs": 126,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.registration.lastheartbeatsec_00480": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.registry.lastupdatesec_00480": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.response.star-star": 13,
>       "gauge.servo.response.swagger-resources.configuration.ui": 19,
>       "normalized.servo.eureka-connection-cleaner-time.totaltime": 0.0009386666666666665,
>       "normalized.servo.eureka-connection-cleaner-time.count": 0.03333333333333333,
>       "gauge.servo.eureka-connection-cleaner-time.min": 0.021162,
>       "gauge.servo.eureka-connection-cleaner-time.max": 0.035158,
>       "counter.servo.eureka-connection-cleaner-failure": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.transport.currentsessionduration": 533378,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.registration.lastheartbeatsec_00120": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.registry.lastupdatesec_00015": 1,
>       "gauge.servo.response.swagger-resources.configuration.security": 4,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.registry.lastupdatesec_00120": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.response.info": 35,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.registration.lastheartbeatsec_00060": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.registry.lastupdatesec_00060": 0,
>       "counter.servo.discoveryclient_reconcilehashcodemismatch": 0,
>       "normalized.servo.discoveryclient_fetchregistry.totaltime": 0.29706815000000003,
>       "normalized.servo.discoveryclient_fetchregistry.count": 0.03333333333333333,
>       "gauge.servo.discoveryclient_fetchregistry.min": 4.337664999999999,
>       "gauge.servo.discoveryclient_fetchregistry.max": 13.486424,
>       "counter.servo.discoveryclient_reregister": 0,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.registry.localregistrysize": 5,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.registry.lastsuccessfulregistryfetchtimeperiod":
>   22920,
>       "gauge.servo.eurekaclient.registration.lastsuccessfulheartbeattimeperiod":
>   22926,
>       "gauge.servo.response.swagger-resources": 5,
>       "integration.channel.errorChannel.errorRate.mean": 0,
>       "integration.channel.errorChannel.errorRate.max": 0,
>       "integration.channel.errorChannel.errorRate.min": 0,
>       "integration.channel.errorChannel.errorRate.stdev": 0,
>       "integration.channel.errorChannel.errorRate.count": 0,
>       "integration.channel.errorChannel.sendCount": 0,
>       "integration.channel.errorChannel.sendRate.mean": 0,
>       "integration.channel.errorChannel.sendRate.max": 0,
>       "integration.channel.errorChannel.sendRate.min": 0,
>       "integration.channel.errorChannel.sendRate.stdev": 0,
>       "integration.channel.errorChannel.sendRate.count": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusInput.errorRate.mean": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusInput.errorRate.max": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusInput.errorRate.min": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusInput.errorRate.stdev": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusInput.errorRate.count": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusInput.sendCount": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusInput.sendRate.mean": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusInput.sendRate.max": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusInput.sendRate.min": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusInput.sendRate.stdev": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusInput.sendRate.count": 0,
>       "integration.channel.hystrixStreamOutput.errorRate.mean": 0,
>       "integration.channel.hystrixStreamOutput.errorRate.max": 0,
>       "integration.channel.hystrixStreamOutput.errorRate.min": 0,
>       "integration.channel.hystrixStreamOutput.errorRate.stdev": 0,
>       "integration.channel.hystrixStreamOutput.errorRate.count": 0,
>       "integration.channel.hystrixStreamOutput.sendCount": 0,
>       "integration.channel.hystrixStreamOutput.sendRate.mean": 0,
>       "integration.channel.hystrixStreamOutput.sendRate.max": 0,
>       "integration.channel.hystrixStreamOutput.sendRate.min": 0,
>       "integration.channel.hystrixStreamOutput.sendRate.stdev": 0,
>       "integration.channel.hystrixStreamOutput.sendRate.count": 0,
>       "integration.channel.nullChannel.errorRate.mean": 0,
>       "integration.channel.nullChannel.errorRate.max": 0,
>       "integration.channel.nullChannel.errorRate.min": 0,
>       "integration.channel.nullChannel.errorRate.stdev": 0,
>       "integration.channel.nullChannel.errorRate.count": 0,
>       "integration.channel.nullChannel.sendCount": 0,
>       "integration.channel.nullChannel.sendRate.mean": 0,
>       "integration.channel.nullChannel.sendRate.max": 0,
>       "integration.channel.nullChannel.sendRate.min": 0,
>       "integration.channel.nullChannel.sendRate.stdev": 0,
>       "integration.channel.nullChannel.sendRate.count": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusOutput.errorRate.mean": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusOutput.errorRate.max": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusOutput.errorRate.min": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusOutput.errorRate.stdev": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusOutput.errorRate.count": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusOutput.sendCount": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusOutput.sendRate.mean": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusOutput.sendRate.max": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusOutput.sendRate.min": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusOutput.sendRate.stdev": 0,
>       "integration.channel.springCloudBusOutput.sendRate.count": 0,
>       "integration.handler._org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler.duration.mean":
>   0,
>       "integration.handler._org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler.duration.max":
>   0,
>       "integration.handler._org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler.duration.min":
>   0,
>       "integration.handler._org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler.duration.stdev":
>   0,
>       "integration.handler._org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler.duration.count":
>   0,
>       "integration.handler._org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler.activeCount":
>   0,
>       "integration.handlerCount": 1,
>       "integration.channelCount": 5,
>       "integration.sourceCount": 0,
>       "httpsessions.max": -1,
>       "httpsessions.active": 0,
>       "datasource.primary.active": 0,
>       "datasource.primary.usage": 0 }

Code flow doesn't even go to the method(tried to use debugger).
The problem with only this newly created endpoint. Last error was

> Full authentication is required to access this resource

until I wrote the piece of configuration:

```
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

I use

```
springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
springCloudVersion = 'Dalston.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with Spring Cloud [MetricsInterceptorConfiguration](http://static.javadoc.io/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-core/1.2.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/metrics/MetricsInterceptorConfiguration.html).

As far as I understood, on each endpoint you can add suffix-path /metrics to see the metrics for this endpoint provided by Spring Cloud. So it just intercepted my mapping :)

I solved this by adding the following configuration to **bootstrap.yml**:

```
endpoints:
  metrics:
    enabled: false
```